# Laravel 5 doesn't route to page in view, when added in routes.php

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I 'm new to LARAVEL 5 ,so i have created **about.blade.php**  in **~/project/resources/views** and then add this  code in **app/routes.php** in order to view the page when requested in browser:

```
Route::get('about', function () {
    return view('about');
});
```

========================================================================
Then i requested in browser as this : **http://localhost:8000/about** .

so this error is shown in browser :

[[image: Laravel Routing Error[1]]

Comment: Though I don't have the solution as everything seems ok to me. But ss per the exception is saying, it cannot find the route(`about`) you are trying to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue using `sudo` command with `php artisan serve`

It was Permission issue .